# Garage door keeps moving forever

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener, garage-door

The problem is with motorized garage door Promatic 4 by Hörmann. The door kept occasionally opening on its own, and was disconnected while the house owners were out of town. After their return, the door stopped functioning normally: when plugged to electric outlet and commanded to open (remotely or via the button), it opens, but then immediately proceeds to close, then opens again and so on, in seemingly endless cycle (I didn't test for how long it can last, out of fear of mechanical failure.)

There's the red LED flashing 10 times, making a pause, then flashing again 10 times, etc. According to the manual this means either electricity problem (which does not seem to be the case) or that all the signal codes were erased (which doesn't seem to be the case either.)

The solution that I am thinking to try (prior to turning to specialists), is to reinitialize the device to factory settings. Any suggestions/experience will be appreciated.

Comment: This can come from improper adjustments.  Unplug the opener for 10 minutes. Try the door again.  If you still have the same problem, consult the troubleshooting section of the instructions . If you don't have them look them up online.  We cannot because you did not provide the make and model of the opener.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is always to disconnect the garage door opener and **verify correct manual operation** with it disconnected. If a spring has broken or the door is binding in the tracks, that needs to be fixed, so the door operates as it should, easily by hand, and stopping wherever you let it go, not shooting up nor falling down.

Garage door openers are not a substitute for properly adjusted garage door springs.

Then you can try going through the inital setup instructions in the opener's manual to verify that all the sensors and settings are adjusted properly, or to verify that the opener does not appear to work as described in the manual when you attempt to follow those instructions.

If the sensor adjustments go correctly, operation should return to normal.

The latter case is a sign that it's time to replace the opener, as its tiny computer brain may be fried. A surge supressor on the outlet serving it is usually a good bet to reduce those problems for the next opener. In most cases a replacement motherboard will be a significant fraction of the cost of a new opener and be supplied without warranty or ability to return it, while a new opener will have a warranty, so it's often safest (fiscally) to replace the whole thing, in the event that a new motherboard does not fix the problem and you end up spending more to repair the old one than a new one (with warranty) would cost.